# V1Node not working with Kubectl kubernetes-client

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am getting `Unexpected unknown resource type: class io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Node` when `Kubectl.get(V1Node.class).execute()` is calle

I need the list of nodes using kubectl commands via API

Comment: What is your Kubernetes version?

Comment: 1.21.12-gke.1700

Comment: Adding modelMapper is the solution